# counting subquery in SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following query to count how many times each `process_track_id` occurs in a table:

```
SELECT
    a.process_track_id,
    COUNT(1) AS 'num'
FROM 
    transreport.process_name a
GROUP BY
    a.process_track_id
```

This returns the following results:

```
process_track_id  |  num
    1   14
    2   44
    3   16
    5   8
    6   18
    7   17
    8   14
```

This is great. Now is the part where I am stuck. I would like to get the following table:

```
num count
8   1
14  2
16  1
17  1
18  1
44  1
```

Where num are the distinct counts from the first table, and count is how many times that frequency occurs.

Here is what I have tried (it's a subquery, but I'm not sold on the method) and I haven't been able to get it to work just yet. I'm new to SQL and I think I'm missing out on some some key aspects of the syntax.

```
SELECT
    X.id_count,
    count(1) as 'num_count'
FROM
    (SELECT
        a.process_track_id,
        COUNT(1) AS 'id_count'
    FROM 
        transreport.process_name a
    GROUP BY
        a.process_track_id
        --COUNT(1) AS 'id_count'
    ) X;
```

Any ideas?

It's probably good to keep in mind that this may have to be run on a database with at least 1 million records, and I don't have the ability to create a new table in the process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the subquery method you were driving at:

```
SELECT id_count, COUNT(*) AS 'num_count'
FROM (SELECT a.process_track_id
            ,COUNT(*) AS 'id_count'
      FROM transreport.process_name a
      GROUP BY a.process_track_id
      )sub
GROUP BY id_count
```

Not sure there's a better method as the aggregation needs to run once anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Goat Co and Jade. Accepting the first answer here, but voting both.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
SELECT x.num, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.process_track_id, -- <--- You may removed this column
        COUNT(*) AS 'num'
    FROM 
        transreport.process_name a
    GROUP BY
        a.process_track_id
        ) X
GROUP BY X.num
```